# Parsing a dimension field with variable formatting in Teradata?

Tags: parsing, regexp-substr

I have a dimension field that holds data in the below format. I am using teradata to query this field.

1. 10 x 10 x 10
2. 5.0x6x7
3. 10 x 12x 1
4. 6.0 x6.0 x6.0
5. 0 X 0 X 0

I was wondering how should I go about parsing this filed to only obtain the numbers into 3 different columns.

Comment: Please supply further detail and the relevant code that you already have

Comment: I am currently using the following code but it doesn't capture everything entirely. Especially if there is a ".0" at the end of the code.  cast(TRIM(StrTok(dimensions, UPPER (' x'),1))as decimal (18,0))  as prod_length,
    cast(TRIM(StrTok(dimensions, UPPER (' x'),3)) as decimal (18,0)) as prod_width,
    cast(TRIM(StrTok(dimensions, UPPER (' x'),5)) as decimal (18,0))  as prod_height

Comment: I have also tried using this other code but it doesn't capture the last column well either dimensions, cast(regexp_substr(dimensions, '[0-9]+') as int) as l, cast(substr(regexp_substr(dimensions, 'x +[0-9]+'), 3, 10) as int) as w, cast(substr(regexp_substr(dimensions, 'x +[0-9]+'), 5, 10) as int) as h

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work or at least get you close.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '(.*?)(x ?|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 1) AS length,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '(.*?)(x ?|$)', 1, 2, 'i', 1) AS width,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '(.*?)(x ?|$)', 1, 3, 'i', 1) AS height
```

Return the first captured group of a set of characters that are followed by a case-insensitive 'x' and an optional space or the end of the line.  The 4th argument is the instance of this match to return.

Comment: That resulted in getting a "Function 'REGEXP_SUBSTR' called with an invalid number or type of parameters" error.

Comment: Read up on the regexp_substr function.  try removing the last parameter.